# Angular 6 - no manifest was fetched

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to use a Service worker in my app.

I've added `@angular/pwa`,
registered the service worker:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {
        scope: '/'
    }).then((registration) => {
        console.log("Service worker OK!")
    });
}
```

When i run Google Lighthouse on my local everything work perfect, and the site works in online mode, but whednI upload my app to server I recive an error in Lighthouse:

```
No manifest was fetched.
```

Do I use a wrong path?

```
manifest.json:
"start_url": "/index.html",
```

Comment: Please add lighthouse report screenshot or link to your app.

Answer (score 7):

That error means that your `index.html` file doesn't tell browsers about the manifest. Add:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Answer (score 6):

After adding the `@angular/pwa`, double check these:

1.In your `angular.json` file, under assets, add the `manifest.json`, like below

```
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/manifest.json"
        ],
```

2.Your `manifest.json` file should be in the `src/` directory, so `src/manifest.json`

3 Then in your `ngsw-config.json` file, you should have this:

```
  "files": [
    "/favicon.ico",
    "/index.html",
    "/manifest.json"
  ],
```

Do the three steps above, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

For me putting the manifest at the top section of the head tag did it.  I was loading scripts embed scripts from Facebook and Twitter, and angular had placed the 
at the bottom of head tag.  Moving it above the scripts section somehow fixed it.